# Is it possible to have two servlet connection in single jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have Created 1.jsp file containing

NAME

CARNAME

ADDRESS

This fields are added to database(table1) by using servlet codeing (1.servlet)

In (2.servlet) i write code as if user given carname is same as the database (table2) it will retrive agencyname from table 2

and

display in (2.jsp).

How can i link these???

**1.jsp**
CAR NAME

```
         <input type="text" name="carname" value=""  /><br><br>
```

**1.servlet**

In this i write code to insert the carname in table1

**2.servlet**

In this i write code to retrive agencyname for the carname given by the user from table2 and display in 2.jsp

Comment: It's completely unclear to me what you are asking.

Comment: I just guess: the jsp contains one form to store new car and second form to seek car / agency?

Comment: @LeosLiterak u r correct

Comment: each form will have different action attribute pointing to one of servlet

Comment: but i neet in single jsp 2 servlet hav to be call

Comment: If there are two forms, then there are two buttons and user will press just one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Strange requirement, but if that what you need yet, you can do it via the servlet dispatcher forward function.  1.jsp collect the data, take all 3 fields and use the request dispatcher and forward to 1.servlet, when 1.servlet finish, just simply call another request dispatcher and forward control to the 2.servlet and finally forwarding to 2.jsp for rendering to html.

JSP --> 1.servlet

```
ServletContext sc = this.getServletContext();
RequestDispatcher rd = sc.getRequestDispatcher("/tst/1.servlet");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

1.servlet --> 2.servlet

```
ServletContext sc = this.getServletContext();
RequestDispatcher rd = sc.getRequestDispatcher("/tst/2.servlet");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

2.servlet --> 2.jsp

```
ServletContext sc = this.getServletContext();
RequestDispatcher rd = sc.getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/2.jsp");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

Note that the forward() method clears the output buffer.  So, only 2.jsp have any data to send back to browser.  If you need extra information pass, you would have to pass it through the session or request attributes.

Comment: 1.servlet and 2.servlet is not connecting.i am getting error